# cv2.aruco.CharucoBoard_create not found in OpenCV 4.7.0

Tags: python, opencv

I have installed opencv-python-4.7.0.68 and opencv-contrib-python-4.7.0.68

The code below gives me the following error:
`AttributeError: module 'cv2.aruco' has no attribute 'CharucoBoard_create'`

Sample code:

```
import cv2

aruco_dict = cv2.aruco.getPredefinedDictionary(cv2.aruco.DICT_4X4_50)
board = cv2.aruco.CharucoBoard_create(11, 8, 0.015, 0.011, aruco_dict)
```

Comment: Your cited error message ``getCharucoBoard_create`` - your sample code ``CharucoBoard_create``. Which one is it? Providing the full error message willl help us to help you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is due to a [change](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/22986/files#diff-09508dfcb283f5b8f2e58538584a58ce28d369f8c7e23705f004f7d15e6f40e9) that happened in release 4.7.0, when the Aruco code was moved from contrib to the main repository.

The constructor `cv2.aruco.CharucoBoard_create` has been renamed to `cv2.aruco.CharucoBoard` and its parameter list has changed slightly -- instead of the first two integer parameters `squaresX` and `squaresY`, you should pass in a single tuple with two values, representing the size. (Note: The [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.7.0/d0/d3c/classcv_1_1aruco_1_1CharucoBoard.html#a6cbc67e2253bb47d1a0f942f9db9efde) seems to be missing the Python constructor's signature. [Bug report](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/23133) has been filed.)

So, your code should look like:

```
import cv2

aruco_dict = cv2.aruco.getPredefinedDictionary(cv2.aruco.DICT_4X4_50)
board = cv2.aruco.CharucoBoard((11, 8), 0.015, 0.011, aruco_dict)
```